# promise is undefined in IE11 when using axios in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, internet-explorer-11

I am coverting my react code to typescript and using axios for network call.
On running in IE11 i get error "Promise is not defined"

I know i need to use polyfill but how? I am not using Babel and Webpack.

I used babel-polyfill.js and error goes away but I get this ERROR

Uncaught Sys.ParameterCountException: Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.

Any idea how could i do it?

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "UMD",
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "lib": ["DOM","ES6","DOM.Iterable","ScriptHost"],
        "typeRoots": []
    },
    "include": [
        "*.tsx"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"        
    ]
}
```

abc.tsx

```
import axios = require('../../Scripts/axios');
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class abc extends React.Component<Props, state> {

function renderabc(res){
  ReactDOM.render(
  <abc resources={res}/>,
  document.getElementById('abc_React')
);  
}
export abc;
```

results expected: axios to work on IE11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`axios` documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#promises) points to [this polyfill](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise), which has instructions for how to include it in your page.

Comment: i looked into this document and i did this.. installed npm es6-promise and added this line of code in axios/lib/core/Axios.js var Promise = require('./../../../es6-promise/es6-promise').Promise; am i doing something wrong?

Comment: it works. i added es-promise.js and es-promise.auto.js scripts in to my folder.